# Why does WP7 ListPicker have different margins and height to TextBox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listpicker

I have a page in my WP7 app consisting of a `TextBox` beside a `ListPicker`.  In their default modes, they don't line up properly; the `ListPicker` has a different padding to the `TextBox`, and its height is also different.

[image: Image to show ListPicker problem]

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/> 
        <toolkit:ListPicker Width="170" ItemsSource="{Binding l}" Style="{StaticResource ListPickerStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Manually tweaking the `ListPicker`'s template to fit in correctly here is tricky and error prone.  For example, when its height is adjusted, the caption (i.e. the text of the selected item) is no longer in the centre of the component.

My app is currently failing MS app review because the components are not all the same height.

Is there an easy way for me to set the `toolkit:ListPicker` to have the same appearance as a `TextBox`?

Comment: Can you apply the same style you are applying to the picker to the textbox as well? Or the other way around, without the picker style how do they line up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution will be to take a copy of the the default style and tweak that using Blend to be exactly how you want it to look. This *will* take a little trial and error to sort out.

You can then use the implicit styling rules to apply it to all `ListPickers` without having to explicitly set the style on each instance:

```
<Style x:Key="MyListPickerStyle
       TargetType="toolkit:ListPicker>
    .... your tweaks here
</Style>

<Style TargetType="toolkit:ListPicker"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MyListPickerStyle}" />
```

It may be easier to tweak the `TextBox` Style of course :)

Comment: I've been trying to do this, but like I say it's difficult and prone to not looking quite right.  `ListPicker` clearly has the same visual appearance as a `TextBox`, so why are its default dimensions different?

Comment: @funkybro - that I don't know. It may be easier to tweak the `TextBox` style so it matches the `ListPicker` style.